# How to convert a Data Flow Diagram (DFD) to Activity Diagram?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, dataflow-diagram

I am trying to learn how to convert a Data Flow Diagram to a Activity Diagram:

[image: DFD image as discussed]

I understand in DFD: The lines between boxes represent data flows, where in activity diagram the lines between boxes represent transition between activities.

I also understand that activity diagram is more powerful and is able to show control, but I cant really wrap my head around how to make a proper conversion from a DFD to Activity Diagram?

Would the lines in a DFD become the boxes in Activity Diagram?

Comment: Check examples in http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-examples.html, rectangles with square corners represent object nodes and lines pointing to them represent [object flow](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams.html#object-flow-edge)

Answer (score 3):

You can draw equivalent activity diagrams using object flows, data stores, and then pins on your activities. You don't even need control flows. For more information about how activity diagrams behave, read the series written by Conrad Bock: http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_07/column3/